# Why did Pharaoh think he was G-d unless he could do things G-d could do? Could Pharaoh make man, on an outer level?

Tags: parashas-shemos, shemot-exodus, golus-exile, pharaoh

Like for example, G-d creates human beings. Could Pharaoh create human beings too such that he would believe he was G-d? G-d can also create all types of human beings. If Pharaoh could create Egyptians but not Jews, wouldn't that prove to him he wasn't G-d? Or could he in fact do that? Of course only Hashem can create a Jew's soul and essence but could Pharaoh create people's bodies in an exilic, kelipah state, so to speak, that he would think he was G-d? Shemos teaches that Klal Yisrael were created as a people in the iron furnace of Egypt, so I'm wondering if there is a level of interpretation where Pharaoh was involved in actually creating the people of that generation, including Klal Yisrael, on the surface level, but that he deceived himself as far as thinking he created their souls and essences too when of course he didn't?

Comment: Another level to why Im asking this is trying to better understand where chazal, so to speak, draw the line with relation to some of gnosticism's similar concepts to Kabbalah, but with crucial differences, viz a viz an evil demiurgic figure being involved in creation. Of course we believe, unlike strains of gnosticism, that Hashem controls everything, so the key difference could be for example what if yes He created certain kelipahs and people under judgement through an evil intermediary such as Pharaoh, but completely under His control, by His plan, unlike gnostic concepts?

Comment: It's not rare to find ordinary humans who think they're gods.

Comment: @shmosel That's true. But do most those examples think they created the world or do they think more along the lines of, "Im a reincarnation or descendant of an angel or some lower case god" within their pagan pantheon? How could you think you're actually upper case G-d, creator of heaven and earth, if every day you can't do many things that G-d clearly does and has done, like make man?

Comment: Is this a Judaism question or an Egyptian history question? If the question is about how Egyptian understood the divinity of their pharaoh, I think this is off topic here.

Comment: The Chabad opinion on this according Rav Friedman is that Pharoah knew about Hashem, and He knew that Hashem wanted the Benei Yisrael to build Him a dwelling place, and He figured that He was also a god, and tried to copy this. This means he was aware he wasn't God, who could create etc, but he was the chief "idol" on earth, above the nile, the sun and the cats :) Egyptian theology has a whole set of rules, including gods do not excrete so that's why he would hide his excretion in the nile. Torah does cover a lot of this but @magicker72 is right, it is _generally_ probably off topic

Comment: @RabbiKaii Pharaoh doing his needs in the Nile is not *actual* Egyptian theology, it's a midrash.

Comment: @magicker72 yes, that's what I meant when I followed that sentence with "Torah does cover a lot of this"

Comment: How do you know Pharoah believed he was a god rather than just using using this status as he claimed he was a god for more authority and control over the Egyptians?

Comment: @magicker72 I had trouble explaining the question, but no, I have no interest in Egyptian theology. If I would summarize the Q, it would be, what capabilities did Pharaoh have according to Talmud Torah and Kabbalah? Did he have any ability to create human beings, or at least their outer husks? As part of the judgement of Egypt, did Hashem create the people of that generation thru Pharaoh in some sense similar to gnostic concepts of the demiurge, with Pharaoh in this case in a role similar to the demiurge? If Im correct its most likely answered in Kabbalah but cant rule out peshat or remez.

Comment: @magicker72 Summarizing: Im referring to the gnostic idea that there is the good true G-d, but that a lower satan type figure is unaware of Him, and believes himself to be the true g-d, and he either creates or thinks he's created a lower world where humans live, and humans are trapped under him until a redemption. 

No world was lower than Egypt. Klah Israel was trapped there. Pharaoh was in charge of this low world like the demiurge in gnosticism. Pharaoh was unaware of the real G-d and thought he was god, like the demiurge. There are many similarities but the differences matter most.

Comment: @magicker72 So if Egypt is a kelipah, and our bodies (particularly in Egypt) were in some sense a kelipah at least relative to our souls, and if Hashem put us in Egypt for judgement, then my question is, did Hashem make us or have us birthed from our mothers normally, and we'd get identified by Pharaoh's men and considered slaves, or, because Pharaoh is the admin (so to speak) of this place of golus, was he somehow involved in the actual creation and birthing of people into his kelipah? *Did Hashem use him as an intermediary for the actual creation and birthing of people in that exile?*

Comment: @magicker72 Like let's say you shoot a video and edit it on your computer. In this analogy, you are G-d, and the video is klah Israel, and youtube is Egypt. Now let's say you want to exile your video onto youtube (upload it to youtube) to put it under judgement. Whatever code your video file has on your computer, to upload it to youtube, youtube first has to combine its code, its dna, into your video. So now not only are you the father of the video, but youtube also is in some sense. And Pharaoh being the head of Egypt, would that make him involved in the creation of the people in Egypt?

Comment: @magicker72 It's a labored analogy but hopefully it works OK. Of course I lack the ability to conceive potential explanations of the great rishonim, achronim, and kabbalists. I am just giving the best rough sketch I can of the question I am wondering about, but if there is such a concept, I expect it to be much more brilliantly formulated and explained than what I could come up with. But if I dont give at least a rough sketch, then no one will know what Im asking, so I tried what I could!

Comment: why do you use "creating human beings" as the way in which Pharaoh would be considered a God? This seems a strawman. The gods of ancient Egypt could do many non-human-creating things.

Comment: The same way people  can believe that cows are gods even though cows don't do anything divine and have even less godly attributes than a king does, a king can believe himself to be one. And people believe anything. Both of those beliefs make at least as much sense as the common current belief that men are woman and women are men depending on identification .

Comment: @bondonk My logic was, I agree with u as far as lower dieties, but to think u are the top G-d, the real G-d, just doing many other magical acts would seem to be unconvincing, because how can u be the real G-d if u cant do everything, or particularly, create humans beings, the central creation on earth? So I thought Pharaoh might figure, "Humans are at the center of my concerns and of all my political and spiritual machinations, so how can I be the true G-d, or even *a* true G-d, if I cant create them? Clearly the real G-d is who created us, since I cant." But maybe he could? Thats why I ask.

Comment: I'm not sure he thought he was a god as much as he claimed he was a god to solidify his authority over the Egyptian populace

Answer (score -1):

Go to YouTube, Look at the videos from history channel, or from discovery, they will paint you a very different picture of how the biblical times actually were, specifically from the Egyptians point of view.

They were masters of vibrations, magic, mental manipulation, they were connected to a higher awareness (that can be achieved today) If you also read the meam-loez on genesis you can get a greater insight as well.

Pretty much everything that could be done would be done. One of the reasons sex was very rampant in Egypt is because they are using areas of the brain that is responsible for the hormonal effects in the body, as well is responsible for success in your life,

> "Ventral Tegmental Area Dopamine Cell Activation during Male Rat Sexual Behavior Regulates Neuroplasticity and d-Amphetamine Cross-Sensitization following Sex Abstinence,"(Beloate, L. N., Omrani, A., Adan, R. A., Webb, I. C., Coolen, L. M. (2016).

While in a state meditation that can be applied while living your regal daily life.

Why would that information be important?

Avoda ZARA the word zara can connote to zera = life, studying Kabbala and basic magic you will learn that in order to perform magic or anything in the sense you would need to tap in too a life force, interior or exterior, the goal is to get a balance of both,

(Tora in the correct settings or formula, will bring you to white magic)

hence why every success coach or trainer will say, new energy equals a new life,  or you need to bring life into you to be successful, aka, you need to activate the above parts of the brain, that can be done with extreme/intense thought, sex, or with exercise.

Manipulation of the energy is key,

Now we know that size matters in the world, (not if your seeing the world plainly) as plain physics dictates, the larger object would attract/pull/draw (in comparison to) the smaller objects. This is seen in with people as well, night clubs, concerts anywhere where there's a large group of people, this is why men have a thing about size as they might loose their girl (granted if the girl is weak or un-loyal increasing the odds of her leaving), now we know everything is intention, so if you use your size to drawdown to you the energy of wisdom, wealth, health, power etc, you can even change the direction of energy flow in your favor, change the mood of the area that your in, and lead with compassion, just, wisdom, you will be doing something good, as Moshe told Arron after being confronted by korach, speak softly though be the man with a big staff (along those lines), another indication size matters, moshe himself was thought to be a giant.

Going back to Pharo, Now that you know something new and how size matters in everything, gives a new insight on the pyramids the sphinx and so on. Pharo now mastered everything we have learned, he saved the largest men for guards not only for intimidation, though also for mental manipulation, imagine controlling tens of thousands of people without marketing, television, cell phones, etc at the same time being the smartest in the country, as well as communicating with other deities, pretty g-d like I would say.

ALSO recall avoda zara connoting to avoda zera, they were worshiping pharos energy and systems he uses to manipulate, so we don't mean g-d like the infinite one, the creator of the universe, think of it like a superhero in comparison to a regular human, remember avoda-zara came from worshiping other deities or other (life = zera)energies with great power.

You can argue they have their own g-ds. Yes they do, though this does not contradict anything, as we mentioned earlier, they were in communication with other deities. If you want to think of it like a world leader as the only individual that may communicate with an angle that looks like a g-d, then using the information to impress millions, as a g-d himself, I can heal, walk on water, read your mind, predict your future, light a candle wick on fire with my energy, I can withstand/hold raw fire... I can fly, I can bring the dead back to lifer I can kill without cause. As you can see I am merely mentioning the simple things i'm sure you can think of more extreme talents, earth quakes, destructions of countries, plagues. like a super hero or villain.

Now you can again argue, that I  don't have  proof of such behavior from that time, and we only know of them worshiping and not manipulating as mentioned. Besides the tora mentioning in parasha Vayera, this weeks parasha, (Jan-19-23), that pharo asked his magicians to replicate what they could and they did until the fifth Aliya.

Below you have some links that will explain more the matter.

Ellison, T. (2021, June 15). Magic in the ancient world: Egyptian deities and uses. TheCollector. https://www.thecollector.com/magic-ancient-world-egyptian-deities/
[https://www.ancient-origins.net/news-science-space-mysterious-phenomena/acoustic-levitation-floating-wave-sound-00684][1]

Falde, N. (2019, June 16). Acoustic levitation: Floating on a wave of sound. Ancient Origins. https://www.ancient-origins.net/news-science-space-mysterious-phenomena/acoustic-levitation-floating-wave-sound-00684

So there you go, if you would like more information please feel free to probe the web.

Hope this answered your question and not redirected you or left you with an unsatisfied or incomplete feeling.

Thank you,
Hope you have a wonderful rest of your day.

Comment: "Go to YouTube, Look at the videos from history channel, or from discovery, they will paint you a very different picture of how the biblical times actually were, specifically from the Egyptians point of view."

Do we poskim like History Channel, or Discovery Channel? 

But really, jokes aside, thanks for taking the time, but I'm not sure your answer contains one Jewish source? You quoted a website twice that has sections talking about underground alien bases and Elon Musk alien stuff.

Comment: @ShipBuilding
A jewish source that don't exist, they will provide a great deal of what if's and so on, in my response, I only defined the context as to why people in the ancient times, would believe one was a g-d, where would you find that information in the jewish sources? IF you are really interested in the topic please go to Kosher Tora School where the very qualified rabbi will explain to you in great depths the jewish mystical sources on aliens demons, and so on. I mean King Solomon used demons to build the temple, not known unless your probe really deep with the rabbi.

Comment: Kabala isn't magic

Comment: Torah is not magic nor does it bring you to magic

Comment: @dude, What was perceived as such was, and what was not is not. The development of the psyche is one thing, entering to another realm encountering forces that give you the power to do, this is then was considered magic, and now under the right formula (combination) a mere frequency tune away.